# Why is Instagram unable to open my image?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, share, instagram

I'm working on integrating Share to Instagram in my iPhone app but I am unable to get the edited image to open in Instagram.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
    mainToolBar.hidden = YES;
    colorToolBar.hidden = YES;
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 416));
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * imageA = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(), 1.0)];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    mainToolBar.hidden = NO;
    colorToolBar.hidden = NO;

    NSString * documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSString * savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.ig"];

    NSData * imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageA);

    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];

    NSURL * imageUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:savedImagePath];

    UIDocumentInteractionController * docController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];
    docController.delegate = self;
    [docController retain];

    docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";

    [docController setURL:imageUrl];

    [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

If I set the imageData to equal UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image) the image does show up, but just the original, not the edited image (drawing/coloring app).

Can anyone help me see what I am missing?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I found the solution.  My code needed to be moved into the NSURL format provided by Instagram and I also had to change the image size to be 612 x 612